# How can I create C# desktop application with XCode for Mac OS?

Tags: xcode, macos

Is there any other solutions to create desktop application for Mac with C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use C#, you can use [mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) to develop WinForms applications.

Answer (score 0):

Mono is what you need, either use [their IDE](http://www.mono-project.com/) or there also seems to be a [plugin for XCode](http://code.google.com/p/cocoa-sharp-dev/wiki/CSharpPlugin)